# button can not be resolved

Tags: java, android

This is my starting activity. I'm trying to get this button to work but it's been giving me this error.

Line 15 button can not be resolved.

```
    package com.synamegames.giveaway;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GiveawayActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks

            }
        });
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is You have defined the Button instances as register in the line `final Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);` But you are setting onclick listener to the button instance which is not defined. You should have

```
register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

instead of

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this..

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  findViewById() can only be called after setContentView().  Otherwise, android doesn't know which layout file to look in for R.id.register

Comment: Nope, it still says button can not be resolved. Is it because i need to create an OnClickListener class? Or does my importing of the view.view.onclicklistener void that?

Comment: @drake check my answer and if find this is right then upvote and right this answer so more help to other also..

Comment: @drake Did you make sure to replace `button.setOnClickListener` with `register.setOnClickListener`?

Answer (score 1):

U can use android:onClick from xml and pass a the view into the .java file
eg:

```
android:onClick="bactToList"
```

in java:

```
   public void bactToList(View view){

   }
```